# Xdebug not breaking on breakpoints after new HD

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, phpstorm, xdebug

#### The problem:

I can not get xdebug to work with PhpStorm or NetBeans in localhost. I have the proper Xdebug ext installed based on the wizard. I can see Xdebug is installed properly from `phpinfo()` and `php -v` output. I got a new hard drive at work with a new OS install and ever since then I can't get Xdebug setup to work.

I can not get the breakpoints to hit when accessing the application through the web/Postman. It's like the breakpoints aren't there or no connection is detected. There is no log file generated.

#### What does work:

In PhpStorm I hit the debug phpunit.xml icon then it runs my PHPUnit tests and Xdebug does work, breakpoints are hit, and log files are generated.

#### I have tried:

- Many versions of Xdebug including 2.55, 2.60, 2.61 both 64 and 32 bit and both thread safe and non thread safe
- Hosting with `php -S` and with XAMPP Apache
- NetBeans and PhpStorm

#### My php.ini xdebug section

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension=C:\xampp7.1\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.1-vc14.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log=C:\xampp7.1\php\ext\xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

I don't know what else to try. I thought maybe it could be a company firewall issue or something but none of my coworkers have this issue nor did I before the new HD. I'm on Windows 10 Enterprise could it be some Windows configuration?

Comment: 1) Just in case -- double check that you are editing the right `php.ini` -- your setup may use different configs for CLI environment (PHPUnit debug) and web. 2) Make sure that `phpinfo()` output is checked where it does not work (for a similar reasons). Make sure that your settings are actually present there 3) Collect xdebug log and see what it has to say -- where it tries to connect (if it tries at all). 4) If still nothing -- some screenshots or even better a small screencast might help (to see what you have got there .. maybe you are missing some nuance/details)

Comment: where php = C:\xampp7.1\php\php.exe
php -v  shows Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
php.ini file location : c:\xampp7.1\php\php.ini

There are no logs to check when making a web request because none are created.

What types of screenshots would help? I can try adding screenshots of everything I suppose

Comment: Try with `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` .. or by placing `xdebug_break()` in your code (try debugging very simple script first instead of real project code) -- see if that will produce a log.

Comment: xdebug_break() did not work, but... xdebug.remote_autostart=1 worked!

Answer (score 1):

Credit to LazyOne for figuring out the solution!

Adding xdebug.remote_autostart=1 to the php.ini worked! Thanks so much